# .data('bs.popover') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I'm migrating application from `angular.js` to `Angular 5`..
Application is using bootstrap theme, which uses `bootstrap v3.3.7`. I copied every `css` and `script` and the weird thing is that `popover` (user drop-down) not working in new application any more.
I'm trying to debug it and found that the problem is `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').data("bs.popover")` is `undefined`.

```
$(document).on("click", '[data-toggle="popover"]', function (o) {
        o.stopPropagation(),
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]')
                .data("bs.popover")
                .tip()
                .hasClass("in") ? (
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("hide"),
                    $(document).off("click.app.popover")
                ) : (
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("show"),
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(document).one("click.app.popover", function () {
                            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("hide")
                        })
                    }, 1)
                )
    })
```

And my html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    ...
    <li>
        <button data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title="">
            <img class="img" src="assets/images/img-1.jpg">
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When `button[data-toggle="popover"]` is clicked, html below should be shown:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden">
    <li>
        <a href="#/profile">
            <span class="profile-link"></span> Profile
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `undefined` because you don't have `bs.popover` as a data attribute in your `html` and it's trying to read the `data-bs.popover` that doesn't exist

if you have `<div data-foo="bar"></div>` then `$('div').data('foo')` will output **bar**

https://api.jquery.com/data/

> The `.data()` method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   from memory leaks.

to display the `ul` inside the `popover` you need to put it in the `data-content` attribute and add `data-html="true"` to let the popover know it's displaying `html` ,

i don't know what are you trying to do with all that `.data()` `.tip()` `.hasClass()` ...etc when you could've just replace it with `$().popover()` , here's a working `popover` :

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();


/*

// this will work too

$(document).on("click", '[data-toggle="popover"]', function (o) {
 o.stopPropagation(),
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]')
     .hasClass("in") ? (
         $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("hide"),
             $(document).off("click.app.popover")
            ) : (
             $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("show"),
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     $(document).one("click.app.popover", function () {
                         $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("hide")
                        })
                    }, 1)
                )
})
*/
```

```css
button{
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <button 
      data-toggle="popover" 
      data-original-title="" 
      title=""
      data-html="true"
      data-content='<ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li><a href="#/profile"><span class="profile-link"></span> Profile</a></li></ul>'>
      <img class="img" src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100">
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```